# Zookeeper server starts, but does not stay started

Tags: macos, apache-zookeeper

When starting the server using the command:

`zkServer start`

I get the following response:

`JMX enabled by default
 Using config: /usr/local/etc/zookeeper/zoo.cfg
 Starting zookeeper ... STARTED`

awesome, right ? Nope, zookeeper does not stay started... when I run `zkServer start` again I get the same exact response... forever.  I should be getting this, when running the start command again:

`MX enabled by default
Using config: /usr/local/etc/zookeeper/zoo.cfg
Starting zookeeper ... STARTED
sh-3.2# zkServer start
JMX enabled by default
Using config: /usr/local/etc/zookeeper/zoo.cfg
Starting zookeeper ... already running as process 8086.`

I checked activity monitor and the service is not running either, which I guess it just shows up as 'Java'.

To install/config zookeeper I did this:

- brew install zookeeper
- sudo easy_install kazoo
- cp /usr/local/etc/zookeeper/zoo_sample.cfg /usr/local/etc/zookeeper/zoo.cfg
- zkServer start

Colleagues doing the same steps do not have this problem.... Any Ideas ?

Comment: If you post zookeeper.out (or zookeeper.log) we'd have a better chance to help.  I like zk but it can be a bit quirky to get started.

Comment: I was facing the same problem. I just did a couple of things and zookeeper started in the console: (1) My java path was not correct. check using echo $JAVA_HOME (2) I ran the process in background i.e. zkServer.sh start &.

Comment: It seems tmux and zookeeper don't like each other. Error: 'nohup: can't detach from console: Inappropriate ioctl for device.' Simply starting it outside of tmux worked for me.

Comment: rm /usr/local/var/run/zookeeper/data/zookeeper_server.pid

Comment: I had the same problem.I had started it from zookeeper/bin$ ./zkServer.sh start instead of zookeeper$ ./bin/zkServer.sh start.Strange!!

Comment: @jbcurtin - bless your heart, sir.  tmux was the issue for me.  I didn't have many hairs left to pull out, but I was working on them until I found your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I build the zookeeper from source and it worked, so something must be hosed with the homebrew zookeeper sometimes. a weird bug.